# where datediff < 15 from today in query builder laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-query-builder

I have field in my table product like this

```
--exp_date--
2016-08-02
2016-08-28
2016-08-28
2016-08-23
2016-08-15
2016-08-05
2016-08-20
```

`exp_date` already in `date` format in mysql
I want to `select` data which date remaining `exp_date` less than 15 from today

i aleady try something like this

```
$dn = date('Y-m-d');          //today date
$query = DB::table('product')->where(DB::raw('datediff(exp_date), $dn') < 15)->get();
```

but i get this error 
 `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression could not be converted to int`

how to fix it?

ps:
i used laravel 4.2 and prefer it's by query builder or raw query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This code

```
$expDate = Carbon::now()->subDays(15));
Table::whereDate('exp_date', '<',$expDate);
```

Comment: i get this error `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to string`

Comment: did you put get() method at end. Table::whereDate('exp_date', '<',$expDate)->get();

Comment: oops...forgot that :)

Comment: hmm...i still get data far away from expDate....i mean let's say my rule if a product will in notice if exp date less than 15 days from now...but when i tried with 16 or more days it's still in query...where i'm wrong?

Comment: If You only want the past 15 days records then change the condition to >=

Comment: i still get data which exp in october. . . .

Comment: Table::whereDate('exp_date', '>=',$expDate)->whereDate('exp_date', '<=',Carbon::now()); expiry date greater than past 15 days and less than today

Answer (score 7):

Date Difference works for me in Laravel Query.

```
DB::table('product')->whereRaw('DATEDIFF(exp_date,current_date) < 15')->get();
```